# Android What does claimInterface really do?

Tags: android, usb, endpoint

On Android , an USB function of claimInterface https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#claimInterface(android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface, boolean) is provided. Currently, if  passing on TRUE to claimInterface as the 2nd parameter, then I will fail to receive data by calling bulktransfer. The returned value is -1 . whereas , if FALSE is passed , I can receive data successfully by calling bulktransfer. Would you please help to clarify what claimInterface does potentially . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claims exclusive access to a UsbInterface. This must be done before sending or receiving data on any UsbEndpoints belonging to the interface.